# Access violation when using delete

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have these two classes bellow and a third class named "creature" which has two constructors.

```
class Neuron
{
public:
    Neuron(int nWeights);
    void Mutate();

    void calculateOutput( std::vector<Neuron*>* previousLayer );
    void changeOutput( float output );                                      // this function is for the input neurons
    float returnOutput();


private:
    std::vector<float> weights;                                             // the first weight is the thresholdWeight
    float output;
};

class NeuralNet
{
public:
    NeuralNet(std::vector<int> netInfo);
    ~NeuralNet();
    void Mutate();

    void CalculateOutputs();
    void UpdateInputs( std::vector<float> inputs );
    void AddLayer( std::vector< Neuron* > *layer );
    std::vector<float> ReturnOutputs();
    std::vector< std::vector< Neuron* >* >* ReturnLayersPointer();
private:
    std::vector< std::vector< Neuron* >* > layers;                          // The first layer is the input layer so the outputs of its neurons are given not calculated 
};
```

The two constructors are:

```
creature::creature(vector2D startPosition, float maxSpeed, float radius, std::vector<int> netInfo)
    :
position(startPosition),
maxSpeed(maxSpeed),
radius(radius)
{
    neuralNet = new NeuralNet( netInfo );
    nGreensCollected = 0;

    testMap.resize( MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE );
}

creature::creature( creature* parent )
{
    position = parent->ReturnPosition();
    maxSpeed = parent->ReturnMaxSpeed();
    radius = parent->ReturnRadius();
    neuralNet = new NeuralNet( *parent->ReturnNeuralNetPointer() );
    neuralNet->Mutate();

    nGreensCollected = 0;
    testMap.resize( MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE );
}
```

When i try to delete creatures that are made using the first constructor no problem arises but the creatures made using the second constructor give me an unhandled exception. Here is the destructor for the NeuralNet class:

```
NeuralNet::~NeuralNet()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < layers.size(); i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < (*layers[i]).size(); j++ )
        {
            delete (*layers[i])[j];
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i create the creatures that I can delete with no problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    vector2D vPosition;
    vPosition.x = 25000;
    vPosition.y = 25000;
    std::vector<int> netInfo;
    netInfo.push_back(39);
    netInfo.push_back(39);
    netInfo.push_back(2);
    creature* pCreature = new creature(vPosition,1,20,netInfo);

    creatureSystem->AddCreature( pCreature );
}

void CreatureSystem::AddCreature( creature* pNewCreature )
{
    creatures.push_back( pNewCreature );
}
```

And this is how i create the creatures that give the errors when deleted( last 6 lines ):

```
void CreatureSystem::NaturalSelection()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> performances;
    performances.resize( creatures.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < creatures.size(); i++ ) 
    {
        std::pair<int,int> temp;
        temp.second = i;
        temp.first = creatures[i]->ReturnAndResetGreensCollected();
        performances[i] = temp;
    }
    std::sort(performances.begin(), performances.end());

    int temp = creatures.size() / 2;
    for( int i = 0; i < temp; i++ )
    {
        if( creatures[performances[i].second] != NULL )
        {
            delete creatures[performances[i].second];
        }
    }
    creatures.erase( creatures.begin(), creatures.begin() + temp );

    for( int i = 0; i < temp; i++ )
    {
        creature* pChildCreature = new creature( creatures[i] );
        AddCreature( pChildCreature );
    }
}
```

Creature class:

```
class creature
{
private:
    NeuralNet* neuralNet;
    /*  The inputs represent the r, g, b values of the tiles as shown at CreatureSystem::returnInputs( vector2D position ).
        The outputs are the components of the velocity vector( 0.5 is not moving, 1 is moving at full speed in that direction, 
        0 is moving at full speed in the opposite direction ). Outputs[0] is for velocity.x and [1] is for velocity.y
    */
    vector2D position; // the center of the creature
    vector2D velocity;
    float maxSpeed;
    float radius;

    int nGreensCollected;
public:
    std::vector<sf::Color> testMap;

    creature(vector2D startPosition, float maxSpeed, float radius, std::vector<int> netInfo);
    creature( creature* parent );
    ~creature();

    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window, vector2D cameraPosition);
    vector2D ReturnPosition();
    float ReturnMaxSpeed();
    float ReturnRadius();
    void UpdateNetInputs(std::vector<float> inputs);
    void CalculateNetOutputs();
    void UpdateVelocity();
    void UpdatePosition();
    void UpdateTestMap( std::vector<sf::Color>* map );
    void CheckIsOnGreen();
    std::vector<sf::Color>* ReturnMapPointer();
    NeuralNet* ReturnNeuralNetPointer();
    int ReturnAndResetGreensCollected();
    //std::vector<float> returnOutputs();

};
```

Error text: Unhandled exception at 0x6c7bad4a (msvcp100d.dll) in Evolution.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefef2.

Comment: You are using a *lot* of pointers. You should probably try to stop that. The fewer pointers you have the fewer chances there are for something to go wrong. For example, your `NeuralNet::layers` member, it often doesn't make sense to have a vector of pointers to vectors.

Comment: Unless someone sees the problem I will do as you recommend.

Comment: Can you show us the declaration for creature? also a shot in the dark can you make the Neuron destructor virtual? 

EDIT: Realized creature may not be a child on Neuron's can you still show us the declaration of creature though?

Comment: When you do things like `(*layers[i])` I'm not sure if `*` or `[]` is applied first, and if that is the order you intended. Or if `(*layers)[i]` would be better. Using fewer pointers would likely be a huge improvement.

Comment: Should I post all the code in creature.cpp as well?

Comment: Can you post the entire unhandled exception error message as well?

Comment: @CiocanCosmin If for some reason you need to *share* a pointer between your classes, use `std::shared_ptr`, not raw pointers.  Right now, your design sort of lacks coherence on who owns the pointers you're allocating.  For that reason alone you should use shared_ptr, but only if you actually need to use a pointer, as a lot of entities will be ok if they're just values, not pointers.

Comment: I will certainly try everything you suggested. Thanks guys.

Comment: I believe the issue has something to do with your erase and your std::sort, if performances is being sorted on the first int, then the order of your performance is not the same as your creatures, 

So when you call the delete creatures[performances[i]->second] the second value is not the same as i, when you call erase you are calling erase from the beginning to the temp, which does not cover the range you deleted, so when you create your creatures afterwards some of the creatures were deleted so you are accessing memory recently freed hence the 0xfeeefef2 error you are getting.

Comment: To clarify more clearly is temp is 2 you are erasing from the beginning of the vector to the 2 index of the vector, however if you delete creatures[performances[i]->second] and second is 3 then your first index that you are accessing after your erase is a pointer you deleted.

Comment: Oh. So i might be left with already deleted pointers and me trying to delete them again is causing the problem?

Comment: @CiocanCosmin Yes, in a release environment there is no guarantee to what that pointer would be pointing at, so after being cleaned up it could point somewhere else entirely and you could be accessing memory that you didnt allocate and can cause undefined behaviour.  Thats why I mentioned setting it to null and then erasing the indices that are null, because in a release environment you will still be telling that pointer where to look and you can still test against null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add comments where the issues are but here is your code:

```
void CreatureSystem::NaturalSelection()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> performances;
    performances.resize( creatures.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < creatures.size(); i++ ) 
    {
        std::pair<int,int> temp;
        temp.second = i;
        temp.first = creatures[i]->ReturnAndResetGreensCollected();
        performances[i] = temp;
    }
    std::sort(performances.begin(), performances.end());

    int temp = creatures.size() / 2;
    for( int i = 0; i < temp; i++ )
    {
        if( creatures[performances[i].second] != NULL )
        {
            // Second could be > temp
            delete creatures[performances[i].second]; 
        }
    }
    // Essential erasing indices 0 - temp, but if second was greater then temp
    // you are leaking memory, and you have recently freed pointers in your list
    creatures.erase( creatures.begin(), creatures.begin() + temp );
    // if size was 5 temp is 2 due to truncation, you could possibly be missing a creature here when setting a parent.
    for( int i = 0; i < temp; i++ )
    {
        // Could be a freed pointer therefore you are accessing uninitialized memory causing your exception
        creature* pChildCreature = new creature( creatures[i] );
        AddCreature( pChildCreature );
    }
}
```

Since you are possibly not calling delete on the pointers within a range of 0 - temp (of creatures), you are possibly erasing indices of pointers that still exist, and possibly leaking memory, The easiest method to test this theory would be to do this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < temp; i++ )
{
    if( creatures[performances[i].second] != NULL )
    {
        // Second could be > temp
        delete creatures[performances[i].second]; 
        creatures[performances[i].second] = NULL;
    }
}
```

then to iterate through and erase the indices that are now null.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code is realy dirty, i sugest you to use `iterators` to avoid more problems, and maybe you should use `shared_ptr` for the "creatures", in that way you dont need to delete it in the destructor.

Second, you main problem is that you are trying to delete a dirty pointer, this is because you has deleted it previously in the "NaturalSelection" by the line:

```
delete creatures[performances[i].second];
```

Comment: Where should I be using iterators?

Comment: When you fill or delete elements inside a container: for example: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/16-3-stl-iterators-overview/